# How do I make CMD+? work the native way with Firefox for Mac?

Tags: macos, firefox

Any "well-behaved" app on the Mac will let you type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> to open the help menu search box. However Firefox overrides this behavior. Instead of opening the help search box in the menu bar, it opens a page on Firefox's website. I find this extremely annoying. Is there an about:config entry I can add or edit, or some other way, to get the default behavior for <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>

Using Mac OS X 10.6.4, Firefox 3.6.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the way you want it in Firefox 4 (which should be released in a few months).

You can globally change the shortcut (System Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts) to something else, like <kbd>cmd+/</kbd>.

You could also try an extension like [Keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension).

Comment: I didn't even know shortcuts in System Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts could be edited! Nice! (There is no visual indication that they can be edited.)

Comment: I now see there are some textual instructions indicating that the shortcuts can be edited on that pref pane.